# ActiveAdmin update two models in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin page to edit `Loan` info, like that:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Loan do
  ...
  form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Loan' do
    f.input :name
    f.input :amount
  end
  f.actions
end
```

(I'm omitting lot of fields for clarity)

Now, due to performance reasons I extracted `amount` field to `LoanDetails` model that has one-to-one relation with `Loan`

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :details, class_name: 'LoanDetails', foreign_key: :loan_id
  ...
end

class LoanDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :loan
  ...
end
```

This change brakes ActiveAdmin page. Attempt to edit loan results in

```
unknown attribute 'amount' for Loan.
```

error.

How can I update my `ActiveAdmin` to work properly with new data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague helped me to solve this while I was in the middle of writing StackOverflow question.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Loan do
  ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Loan' do
      f.input :name
    end

    f.inputs 'Loan Details', for: [:details, f.object.details] do |d|
      d.input :amount
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```